# How to enable lint on HTML in vs code?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, htmllint

I am developing angular2 app with visual studio code, I have installed the following extensions,

**[`htmllint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmllint)**

and

[`htmlhint-ng2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlhint-ng2)

I have the component template as follows,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'userprofile',
    template: `
            <div class="profilecontainer">  
                <div class="row"> 
                   <img [src]="profile.profilePic" />

                <div   class="row">
                    <h2>{{profile.firstName}} {{profile.lastName}} </h2>
                    <a target="_blank" href="{{profile.detailUrl}}"> View profile</a>
                    <a target="-blank" href="{{profile.editUrl}}">Edit profile</a>
                </div>
           </div>`
})
```

Hml lint does not show any errors on vs code? what is the issue?

Comment: Maybe it sees it as a string, rather that an actual html fragment

Comment: no it dint work even for a normal html

Comment: Have you tried to use html files as template and lint them? It might be trying to lint a ts file, that's incompatible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now, **you can't**.

In order to add extra features (i.e. *linting*) to VS Code you must use an extension made for it and unfortunately, by the time of this answer, there isn't any `htmllint` VS Code extension.

Please note that both links you shared are node modules and not extensions. Installing something with with `npm` (i.e. `npm install htmllint`) will not make it work with VS Code.

You can browse and install extensions from within VS Code, [as describe in it docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery), like this:

> Bring up the Extensions view by clicking on the Extensions icon in the Activity Bar on the side of VS Code or the View: Extensions command (⇧⌘X).

If you can't find the extension you need, you have a few options:

- [Create the extension yourself](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview)
- Change to an Editor that has such extension:

  - Atom: [linter-htmlhint plugin](https://atom.io/packages/linter-htmlhint)
  - Sublime Text: [SublimeLinter-contrib-htmllint package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-contrib-htmllint)
- Find an alternative way to keep using the editor without having to write your own extension.

---

**Suggested Alternative**:

1. Install one of the 2 node modules. (i.e. `npm i htmlhint-ng2 -D`)
2. Add its cli command to a `package.json` script:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "lint:html": "htmlhint-ng2 src/**/*.html"
   }
   ```
3. Test it by running `npm run lint:html`
4. Install the [npm-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-watch) module: `npm i npm-watch -D`
5. Add the watch script and config to `package.json`

   ```
   "watch": {
     "lint:html": "src/**/*.html"
   },
   "scripts": {
     "lint:html": "htmlhint-ng2 src/**/*.html"
     "watch": "npm-watch"
   }
   ```
6. Run `npm run watch`

Answer (score 5):

There is now an official HTMLHint VS Code extension (which replaces the deprecated one built by Microsoft).

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HTMLHint.vscode-htmlhint

The rules can be configured to work with Angular components in HTML.